# Pushing Website Paragraph Data to Organized Google Sheets Columns

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to this, but have been piecing scripts together, living on YouTube, and getting help here to get this far.. I'm very close to my end goal, but can't seem to figure out what exactly is off:

The script below scrapes information from different links.  I had different of versions of this, until someone helped finalize the best way (below):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
        row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url}

        for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
            try:
                key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
            except:     # not all entries have values
                pass

        data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2021',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2020',
]


for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)

    for entry in data:
        print(entry)
```

I then figured out how to push data to Google Sheets from various videos and made a test script that pushes different HREF tags to a G Sheet (below). I was really happy with this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1cD8mX8tR2iSQgSmpk6QxBVVHYVV8VxGs2uhtA8iBSpQ')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


profiles = []
urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2021'
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2020'
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2019'
]
for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profile in soup.find_all('a'):

        profile = profile.get('href')

        profiles.append(profile)

# print(profiles)

for p in profiles:
    if p.startswith('/player'):
        print(p)
        AddValue = [p]
        worksheet.append_row(AddValue)
```

However, my real goal is to get the output of the FIRST script (current output shown below) pushing to a sheet, with the different values funneling into organized columns (like the image below the code).

```
{'Name': 'Khalil Iverson', 'URL': '/player/Khalil-Iverson/Summary/88527', 'Current Team': 'N/A', 'Born': 'Jul 19, 1997(24 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': e, Ohio', 'Nationality': 'United States', 'Height': '6-5 (196cm)Weight:210 (95kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Mike Naiditch',
Entry': '2019 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Wisconsin(Sr)', 'High School': 'Rutherford B. Hayes High School[Delaware, Ohio]'}
{'Name': 'Jarrett Jack', 'URL': '/player/Jarrett-Jack/Summary/366', 'Born': 'Oct 28, 1983(38 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Fort Washington, Maryland', lity': 'United States', 'Height': '6-3 (191cm)Weight:200 (91kg)', 'Hand': 'Right', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Sam Goldfeder', ntry': '2005 NBA Draft', 'Early Entry Info': '2005 Early Entrant', 'Drafted': 'Round 1, Pick 22, Denver Nuggets', 'Draft Rights Trade': 'DEN to POR, Jun 28, 2re-Draft Team': 'Georgia Tech(Jr)', 'High School': 'Worcester Academy[Worcester, Massachusetts]'}
{'Name': 'Kadeem Jack', 'URL': '/player/Kadeem-Jack/Summary/24639', 'Current Team': 'N/A', 'Born': 'Oct 27, 1992(29 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Queenork', 'Nationality': 'United States', 'Height': '6-9 (206cm)Weight:225 (102kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Chris Emens,Josh Bd-Bell', 'Draft Entry': '2015 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Undrafted', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Rutgers(Sr)', 'High School': 'CJEOTO Academy[Somerset, New Jersey]'}
{'Name': 'Demetrius Jackson', 'URL': '/player/Demetrius-Jackson/Summary/43395', 'Current Team': 'N/A', 'Born': 'Sep 7, 1994(27 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometoshawaka, Indiana', 'Nationality': 'United States', 'Height': '6-1 (185cm)Weight:200 (91kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Rade Fh', 'Draft Entry': '2016 NBA Draft', 'Early Entry Info': '2016 Early Entrant', 'Drafted': 'Round 2, Pick 15, Boston Celtics', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Notre Dame(Jrh School': 'Marian High School[Mishawaka, Indiana]', 'AAU Team': 'MBA Select'}
{'Name': 'Josh Jackson', 'URL': '/player/Josh-Jackson/Summary/52032', 'Full Name': "Joshua O'Neal Jackson", 'Current Team': 'N/A', 'Born': 'Feb 10, 1997(25 ye', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'San Diego, California', 'Nationality': 'United States', 'Height': '6-8 (203cm)Weight:207 (94kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestrict
Agent (Sacramento Kings)', 'Agent': 'B.J. Armstrong', 'Draft Entry': '2017 NBA Draft', 'Early Entry Info': '2017 Early Entrant', 'Drafted': 'Round 1, Pick 4, 
Suns', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Kansas(Fr)', 'High School': 'Prolific Prep[Napa, California]', 'AAU Team': 'One Nation'}
{'Name': 'Pierre Jackson', 'URL': '/player/Pierre-Jackson/Summary/28285', 'Current Team': 'N/A', 'Born': 'Aug 29, 1991(30 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': as, Nevada', 'Nationality': 'United States', 'Height': '5-10 (178cm)Weight:180 (82kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Charles Misrrison Gaines', 'Draft Entry': '2013 NBA Draft', 'Drafted': 'Round 2, Pick 12, Philadelphia Sixers', 'Draft Rights Trade': 'PHL to NOP, Jul 10, 2013, NOP to P
27, 2014', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'Baylor(Sr)', 'High School': 'Desert Pines High School[Las Vegas, Nevada]'}
{'Name': 'Justin James', 'URL': '/player/Justin-James/Summary/84791', 'Current Team': 'N/A', 'Born': 'Jan 24, 1997(25 years old)', 'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Porcie, Florida', 'Nationality': 'United States', 'Height': '6-7 (201cm)Weight:190 (86kg)', 'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent', 'Agent': 'Austin Walraft Entry': '2019 NBA Draft', 'Early Entry Info': '2018 Early Entrant(Withdrew)', 'Drafted': 'Round 2, Pick 10, Sacramento Kings', 'Pre-Draft Team': 'WyomingHigh School': 'Oldsmar Christian Academy[Oldsmar, Florida]'}
```

Expected output in Sheets:

[image: Code translated in Sheets]

I tried to figure it out (below), but keep getting issues:

Is this possible? Any guidance is greatly appreciated.  This has been one of the best learning experiences of my life - but I've really hit a brick wall here.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1cD8mX8tR2iSQgSmpk6QxBVVHYVV8VxGs2uhtA8iBSpQ')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
        row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url}

        for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
            try:
                key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
            except:     # not all entries have values
                pass

        data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2021',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2020',
]


for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)

    for entry in data:
        worksheet.append_row(entry)
```

Comment: What does the current output in Google Sheets look like and what should it look like? Show a couple of rows of each? Please include the sample output, which looks to be json, as code not as an image. If you can insert a representative and valid sample so people can verify the structure. You may be able to use pandas to convert that json to a dataframe before writing to Google Sheets.

Comment: Got it - will update my question now; thanks for the tip @QHarr